# Void pointer pointer (void **)

Tags: c++, pointers, com, void-pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I am reading a COM sample at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I really cannot comprehend (void **) in

```
hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
```

So I have tried some values returned by different types of pointers by the class

```
class Point{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int inputX, int inputY){x = inputX, y = inputY;}
    int getX(){return x;}
    int getY(){return y;}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Point &cPoint);
    Point operator-(){
        return Point(-x, -y);
    }
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Point &cPoint){
    return out<< "(" << cPoint.x << ", " << cPoint.y << ")";
}
```

and printing out

```
Point *p = new Point(1,2);
cout << p << endl << &p << endl << endl
<< *&p << endl<< **&p << endl<<endl 
<< (void *) &p << endl << (void **) &p ;
```

(void*) really has no difference with (void **). What does (void **)&pControl want to return?

Comment: `void*` is a pointer to some unknown data type.   `void**` has a more specific type, it is a pointer to a `void*`, they are not the same.  Unless `pControl` is a `void*` this isn't safe behavior.  and if it was a `void*` the cast wouldn't be necessary

Comment: Pointers are *specific* to their type, the lone exception being `void*`, which is simply "untyped". But a pointer-to-(any)-pointer is *always* specifically typed. In this case the underlying decl `void**` is a pointer to pointer-to-void. The cast is needed because `&pControl` evals as the address of a pointer to a specific type (in your case the address of a pointer to whatever type `pControl` is). And `void*`can hold an address from any *data* type; whereas *code* pointers (pointers to functions, member-or-otherwise) are another matter.

Comment: Not any type, but any **data** type.  You can't (safely) have a `void*` assigned a function pointer.  `void*` is how generic's get done in C generally, look at [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) for example.  In C++ we have templates and polymorphism so it's not seen nearly as often

Comment: "404 Page Not Found" though...maybe this? http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/

Comment: @HoyCheung no I just messed up the url syntax, edited.

Comment: So in my case of the Point class, &p is already a (Point**). Why the cast (void*) and (void**) return the same number? What happens if casting fails?

Comment: `void*` is a "generic" pointer type. There is no generic pointer-to-pointer type.

Comment: If you really want to do something with COM, it is best to get every copy of Don Box Books you can fetch.

Comment: When you `cout` a pointer it is converted to `void *` first, so your various casts will not change the output - it doesn't mean the casts do nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
> ```
>
> What does `(void **)&pControl` want to return?

**`QueryInterface()`** is one of the three methods of [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is the base root interface of *all* COM interfaces.

The [MSDN documentation for `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states that:

> ```
> HRESULT QueryInterface(
>   [in]   REFIID riid,
>   [out]  void **ppvObject
> );
> ```
>
> *ppvObject* [out] The address of a pointer variable that receives the interface pointer requested in the *riid* parameter. 
>   Upon successful return, **ppvObject* contains the requested interface pointer to the
>   object. If the object does not support the interface, **ppvObject* is set to **NULL**.

So, in your particular case, upon successful return, `pControl` will contain the requested pointer to the `IMediaControl` interface, as specified in your function call via the first argument `IID_IMediaControl`.

---

Now, let's try to better understand why the double pointer indirection: `void**`.

`void*` means *"pointer to anything"*.

So, one might think: *"Why isn't the second parameter of `QueryInterface()` just a `void*`?"*

The problem is that this parameter is an **output** parameter. This means that `QueryInterface()` will write something *into* that parameter, for the caller to use it.

And, in C (and COM has several C-isms), when you have an *output* parameter, you must use a *pointer* (`*`).
(**Note** In C++ you can also use a reference `&`.)

So, in this case we have the first level of indirection of `void*` that means *"pointer to anything"*.
And the second level of indirection (the other `*`), that means: *"This is an **output** parameter"*.

You can think of it also in this way:

```
typedef void* PointerToAnything;

HRESULT QueryInterface(..., /* [out] */ PointerToAnything* pSomeInterface);

// pSomeInterface is an output parameter.
//
// [out] --> use * (pointer), 
// so it's 'PointerToAnything*' (not just 'PointerToAnything'),
// so, with proper substitution, it's 'void**' (not just 'void*').
```

Comment: So why do you want to use &pControl? I thought the way we use objects is pControl->function(). Using &pControl, we need to use (*pControl)->function() which adds up more hassle.

Comment: In your code, `pControl` should be some pointer to some COM interface (e.g. `IMediaControl*`). But when you pass it to `QueryInterface()`, you must specify _its address_, i.e. the _address of_ `pControl`, so you use `&pControl`. That's because the 2nd parameter of `QueryInterface()` is an **output** parameter.

Comment: No, `QueryInterface()` assigns the _address_ of some COM interface to the pointer. But to do that, `QueryInterface()` needs the address of the pointer (i.e. the address of `pControl`, i.e. `&pControl`).

Comment: I know what you mean now. Thanks